# How to properly trigger an insert to a linked sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, linked-server

I have the same table in two different sql servers (one is SqlServer 2000 and the other 2008).

I'm using sql server management studio.

I want that each time an insert is made on a table in the SqlServer 2000 table (Table_1) a trigger occurs and the record would also be inserted to the same table in the SqlServer 2008 table (also Table_1).

the sql server 2008 is defined as a linked server, and it is possible to run queries and perform inserts on the 2008 db from the 2000 db connection using sql server management studio.

the trigger is defined as follows :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgrTable] 
   ON  [dbo].[Table_1]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO [TLVSQL].[AVI_DEV].[dbo].[Table_1](ID, Value)
      SELECT INSERTED.ID AS ID, INSERTED.Value AS Value
      FROM INSERTED

END
```

the `[TLVSQL].[AVI_DEV]` is the 2008 db name.

But every time i perform an insert on the 2000 table i get a message that the insert failed to commit  due to "sqloledb was unable to begin a distributed transaction linked server ...".

The security delegation of the linked server is well defined, i explicitly set the security credentials to a user/password of a db_owner.

What am i doing wrong ? Is there another way of doing what i ask ?

thank you.

Comment: I agree with the existing answer - from within a trigger, you shouldn't attempt to access anything *external* to the current database. It will severely slow down any insert activity, and if they're are any networking issues or the remote server is down for any reason, you'll then cause the original transaction to roll back. This is rarely the right thing to do - you're making the reliability of your system dependent on the reliability of *two* servers rather than one (say they both have 99% reliability - your system that ties them together with a trigger now has 98% overall reliability)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perform inserts from a trigger into a table on linked server - bad decision.
This will great affects on insert performance in the source table ([dbo].[Table_1])
and also there is a distributed transaction, and configuring servers
for support distributed transactions - nightmare.

One possible solution is:

1. On the source server you can create a synchronization queue table. For example:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.SyncQueue
   (
       QueueId INT IDENTITY(1,1),        
       KeyForSync INT, -- Primary key value of record in dbo.SourceTable
       SyncStatus INT  -- statuses can be: 0 - New, 1 - Synchronized, 2 - Error
   )

   suppose you source table is

   CREATE TABLE dbo.SourceTable
   (
           Key INT, -- primary key of the table
           Data varchar(xxx)
   )
   ```
2. Triger on dbo.SourceTable can quickly insert into dbo.SyncQueue record Key that you need synchronize
3. Some periodically performed stored procedure can then insert records from the queue in
   table on the linked server.

Comment: OK, thanks. performance is not an issue here at all. we are talking on a very small number of records (less than 10 for a week). Though your solution seems wise and clean i need to be able to do it for other tables on which there is no ID key, which means i need to create a sync for a lot of small tables. i'd rather have a solution that i could implement easily on each of the tables 9

Comment: cont. (i cant edit for some reason)  - like a trigger on each - but is it possible even if not advisable ?

Comment: Then yes, in your case, your solution is better. 
If the version of SQL Server was > 2008, you could also use **"Сhange data capture"** feature (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-(cdc)-in-sql-server-2008/).  But you have SQL 2000 .. 
Then you need to properly configure **["Distributed Transaction Coordinator"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684146(v=vs.85).aspx)**. Also see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839279 may be it help you.

Comment: All the info on how to enable the DTC to the right configuration is in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327979.aspx. Another thing i had to do is to set the XACT_ABORT to ON inside the trigger. I end in something like that ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgrTable] 
   ON  [dbo].[Table_1]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET XACT_ABORT ON
         INSERT [TLVSQL].[AVI_DEV].[dbo].[Table_1]
           ([ID]
           ,[Value])
      SELECT INSERTED.ID AS ID, INSERTED.Value AS Value
      FROM INSERTED
END