# SQL Server update two different server by trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have two SQL Server

```
1st - 10.101.102.133 
2nd - 10.101.102.155
```

Both having the different database with different names and fields.

My application will update in the 1st server.

Can I actually configure the 1st server that once it received update query, it will update in 2nd server as well?

I want to insert data from 1st server to 2nd server by using trigger. when my Application insert data in a table in 1st server database a trigger will fire (insert trigger). and it pass the data in 2nd server by its user id and password.

How I write the script of this trigger?

Comment: The official documentation for whichever RDBMS you use will show you how to write a trigger.

Comment: It"s SQL server Mr. Dale K.

Comment: And then read [create trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Inserted/Deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Look this about external data sources https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly trigger an insert to a linked sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126993/how-to-properly-trigger-an-insert-to-a-linked-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Solved here: [Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

You can use [sp_addlinkedserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) or Linked Servers approach.

Using sp_addlinkedserver would be something like this once you have set up the linked server:

```
select
    *
from
    LocalTable,
    [OtherServerName].[OtherDB].[dbo].[OtherTable]
```