# How to insert data from one server table to another server table using a trigger on first server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to directly insert the data from one server table to another server table with an after insert trigger on server 1 table. I have used the following code to do the work. Tables on both the servers have identical columns, table name and schema.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name ON [server1].db.schema.table1
FOR INSERT 
AS

INSERT INTO [server_2].db2.[schema].[table1](
PLANTID
,PLANTNAME
,PLANTLOCATION
,COMPANYNAME
,DISPLAY_STATUS
,VERSION
,DEPARTMENT
,PURPOSE
,PERFORMEDBY
)

SELECT 
PLANTID
,PLANTNAME
,PLANTLOCATION
,COMPANYNAME
,DISPLAY_STATUS
,VERSION
,DEPARTMENT
,PURPOSE
,PERFORMEDBY
FROM INSERTED
order by plmstrauid
```

However, I get the following error. Can anyone please help me with this?

Error:

> The object name '[server1].db.schema.table1' contains more than the
> maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly trigger an insert to a linked sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126993/how-to-properly-trigger-an-insert-to-a-linked-sql-server)

Comment: This is a really bad idea, what happens when server2 is not accessible? Use other means of synchronization (queue, cdc, replication, mirroring) instead.

Comment: I would suggest looking into different methods, such as replication. As @Pred said, this is a bad idea, and will easily (and possibly quickly) cause you headaches.

Comment: `...ON [server1].db.schema.table1` This is your problem. Generally speaking it is a bad habit to use anything more than 2-part names in your sql code. Your connection should determine the database to use for object references. And consider what happens when you need to create multiple environments (development, test, QA, etc.) for your system - a common task. Think VERY carefully about this approach.